# MySQL- How to implement event scheduler everyday + start from 8am to 10 pm+ every 15 min

Tags: mysql, sql, events, scheduler

I would like to insert the statistic into table 1 every 15 min start from 8am to 10pm everyday

How to use MySQL event scheduler to do it?

```
delimiter ||
    CREATE EVENT STOCK_UPDATER
        ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE 
            DO BEGIN
                [INSERT CODE THAT I HAVE MADE]
    END ||
delimiter ;
```

======================================

Thz @Saharsh Shah, I finally solve it, here are my final result:

```
create table ABC (value int(10));

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT ABCevents 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 SECOND 
        DO BEGIN
                IF (HOUR(SYSDATE()) BETWEEN 14 AND 15) THEN
                    insert ABC value(123);
                END IF;
        END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT STOCK_UPDATER 
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE 
      STARTS '2013-11-27 12:00:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
         DO BEGIN
    IF (HOUR(SYSDATE()) BETWEEN 8 AND 22) THEN 
    BEGIN 
         INSERT ABC VALUES (123);
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 9 ----------- I am not sure, but seems it is not correct.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF;
END' at line 8 ------- Another error got ><

Comment: I have create a table ABC, and I change /* [INSERT CODE THAT I HAVE MADE] */ to select * from ABC

Comment: I am sorry but the problem still happen, i have edited my post to show the problem. would u mind help me to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65749/discussion-between-question-er-xdd-and-saharsh-shah).